# Visual Basic - timer keeps looping

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm new to the programming world.

I'm trying to make a simple software which will go through 5-6 forms (showing the progress bar as a picture) and on each form display progress as a picture while some other code is being run in the background. I've written my code and it just keeps looping the application for some reason and I don't know how to stop it from looping.

As I said, I'm new to visual basic and programming world, so please just go easy on me, thanks!

I just need help with stopping the timer after the HandleTimerTick() happens. I don't know how to call the timer to stop, from the previous sub or something. So, I just need a command to stop t.Tick once HandleTimerTick from the second sub starts.

If you have any simpler command to stop the code from executing for the number of seconds feel free to share. Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Delay1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim t As Timer = New Timer()
    t.Interval = 2000
    AddHandler t.Tick, AddressOf HandleTimerTick
    t.Start()


End Sub

Private Sub HandleTimerTick()
    Dim SecondForm As New Delay2
    SecondForm.Show()
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to disable the timer after it ticks.  Writing the event handler correctly is the first step to get there.  Do favor using the designer to make that easy, drop the Timer from the toolbox onto the form.  A decent tutorial or introductory book isn't going to hurt you.

Comment: Declare your `Timer` variable outside with `WithEvents`, then you do not need to add and or remove the handlers. You would also get the correct signatures you are missing... You also need to remove handlers you are creating...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the proper signature for the Event handler  In this way you get a reference to the Timer that trigger the event handler and you can stop it

```
Private Sub HandleTimerTick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ... your code to handle the event

    ' Stop the timer
    Dim t As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    t = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Timer)
    t.Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you guys! Managed to fix everything up with @Steve's suggestion. :) I can't believe I was this blind not to see a few things I had to do, gosh.. sorry if I bothered anyone!

Comment: I don't like to leave wrong answers on the site. If the answer is wrong I would like to know why it is wrong. Please leave a comment.